# What is a blockchain oracle?

Tags: oracles

What is a blockchain oracle for smart contracts? And why is it needed? I've seen a lot of posts about "how do oracles work", and ["what is the oracle problem"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57071/what-is-the-oracle-problem-definition-exactly-and-briefly) but I don't understand what they are?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## A blockchain [oracle](https://cointelegraph.com/explained/blockchain-oracles-explained) is any device or entity that connects a deterministic blockchain with off-chain data.

[Smart contracts cannot make API calls themselves](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/301/why-cant-contracts-make-api-calls/334#334) because they are deterministic, but without being able to interact with data that lives off-chain, they won't be able to utilize the decentrality, security, and reliability a smart contract has. To get data (that powers all our current modern world, i.e., any API that runs your applications) onto the chain, we have to have an off-chain entity create a transaction on-chain with the data posted.

This process of posting data from the real world onto a blockchain is what oracles do.

There are a number of ways to do this. An example of an oracle would be a [Chainlink node](https://docs.chain.link/docs/example-walkthrough), where you can request any API call through the blockchain, and have it post the data on-chain.