# How do i get the price of an erc20 token from solidity smart contract

Tags: oracles, solidity-0.6.x, solidity-0.8.x, solidity-0.7.x

I'm building a dapp, i'm trying to get the erc20 token price in usd from my smart contract how do i go about this? this is very necessary as smart contracts cannot read from outside networks. I don't want my users to be impacted by price change in the token.

Comment: You'll need an oracle to provide the price.

Comment: How do i go about this oracle thing? Sorry if i'm asking too much.

Comment: If it is a well known token you can use Chainlink, otherwise you have to implement your own oracle. For other details check this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/85178/what-is-a-blockchain-oracle.

Comment: Yeah it does but how does one implement an oracle.

Comment: Half the job of a computer scientist is doing research, you should try doing that. Choose an oracle (chainlink is the most commonly used), and find out how to implement it by yourself ( i think this should be a good starting point https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/